# sagemath installation fails on ubuntu 16

Tags: sage, ubuntu-16.04

I need help installing sagemath on my ubuntu 16 laptop.

I did this:

```
cat /etc/os-release 
cd ~
wget http://mirrors.mit.edu/sage/linux/64bit/sage-7.2-Ubuntu_16.04-x86_64.tar.bz2
tar jxf sage-7.2-Ubuntu_16.04-x86_64.tar.bz2
SageMath/sage
```

I saw this:

```
dan@al78:~ $ tar jxf sage-7.2-Ubuntu_16.04-x86_64.tar.bz2
dan@al78:~ $ 
dan@al78:~ $ ll SageMath/sage
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 4680 May 15 16:43 SageMath/sage*
dan@al78:~ $ 
dan@al78:~ $ SageMath/sage
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 7.2, Release Date: 2016-05-15                     │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

ERROR:  The Sage installation tree has moved
```

I'd welcome clues on how to debug this.

Comment: Can you give us the exact problem you got in the `RecursionError`?  This smells like the following three links, all of which are probably due to having a conflicting Python install somewhere. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/R4JVzh03wEU and https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/18279 and especially https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/R4JVzh03wEU

Comment: These were very good clues. The problem was anaconda3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was easy to fix with some shell commands:

```
cd ~
mv anaconda3 anaconda3bak
SageMath/sage
quit
mv anaconda3bak anaconda3
```